# Is there a way to quickly access TODO comments in sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, workflow, sublimetext

The Goto Anything doesn't do the trick for me. Also, how do you keep track of features to implement in a big project in Sublime text? Do you keep a TODO.md file, take notes mentally?

Answer (score 1):

There are several packages for sublime text in [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/search/todo).

- For example to review your todo comments in your code there is [TodoReview](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TodoReview).
- Or for managing a todo list [PlainTasks](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PlainTasks) is quiet nice.